# How to structure a Visual Studio 2012 Solution to host 2 Angular 1.x applications inside Asp.Net projects and yet a common library for Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, gulp, solution

Our team is migrating two related applications form ASP.net to Angular~1.5. These two applications share the database and some code and, therefore, are part of the same solution.

To ease the server-side related issues, we created a folder on each site to hold its own app, as we're incrementally moving functionalities from Asp pages to Angular. Each app is built by its own copy of a gulp-based process.

We have this setup working and the apps build ok, but I'm not very happy with the location for the Javascript code that is shared between the apps. As VS2012 does not provide a better alternative, we've created a folder inside app1 for our shared code and reference it from both app1 and app2.

```
MySolution            (Visual Studio 2012 solution)
|-MyProject_1/        (legacy Asp.Net project)
|-|-MyAngularApp_1/
|-|-|-MyApp_1/        require("../MySharedDir")
|-|-|-MySharedDir/    <== shared library implemented here
|-|-|-package.json
|-|-|-gulpfile.js
|-|-- ...
|-MyProject_2/        (legacy Asp.Net project)
|-|-MyAngularApp_2/
|-|-|-MyApp_2/        require("../../MyProject_1/MyAngularApp_1/MySharedDir")
|-|-|-package.json
|-|-|-gulpfile.js
|-MyWebApi/           (WebApi project)
|-|-- ...
```

Is there a better way to organize the structure of the solution?

Comment: you probably should have a third "shared" project, and a fourth API project. in this way, you can slowly move your angular apps from the shared project to using the APIs, and eventually remove the shared project from active use.

Comment: Hi, @Claies, the solution already have a WebApi project (I just added it to the structure). About the "shared" project , what kind of project would you suggest to use? An important goal we had was to keep the bloatware to a minimum.